# How to implement a generic "options" parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I have a factory that returns objects:

```java
 public class Factory {

        public static Vehicle getVehicle(Options options) {
            if (options.getType().equals("car")) return new Car(options);
            if (options.getType().equals("moped")) return new Moped(options);

        }
    }
```

The objects that the factory creates should be able to take class specific options as parameters:

```java
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car(final CarOptions carOptions) { this.carOptions = carOptions; }
}
```

```java
public class Moped extends Vehicle {
    public Moped(final MopedOptions mopedOptions) { this.mopedOptions = mopedOptions; }
}
```

The options classes:

```java
public class Options {
    // methods
}
```

```java
public class CarOptions implements Options {
    // methods
}
```

```java
public class Moped implements Options {
    // methods
}
```

How can I give the `Factory.getVehicle` method a generic `Options` parameter and have it passed on to the objects the factory creates? I can call `Factory.getVehicle(new CarOptions())` just fine but inside the factory itself the objects expect a specific type of `Options`.

> Required type: CarOptions Provided: Options

I thought that because `CarOptions` implements `Options` I could just pass it on as a parameter to `new Car(options)` but that does not seem to be the case.

I've tried to resolve this by using generics but haven't found a solution that works.

Comment: It would need to cast `options` inside `getVehicle`, like `return new Car((CarOptions) options)`, but in code like `Factory.getVehicle(new CarOptions())` where the type is known at compile time, it would be simpler to use `new Car(new CarOptions())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give `Factory.getVehicle` generic `Options` this interface must be generic: `Options<V extends Vehicle>`.
Now your implementations can setup their specification:

```
CarOptions implements Options<Car>
MopedOptions implements Options<Moped>
```

Since your `Car`/`Moped` constructor needs the specific `Options`implementation you have to cast the parameter in `getVehicle`.
For the generic return value you have to cast as well:

```
public static <V extends Vehicle> V getVehicle(Options<V> options) {
    if (options.getType().equals("car")) { // or options instanceof CarOptions?
        return (V) new Car((CarOptions) options);
    }
    if (options.getType().equals("moped")) { // or options instanceof MopedOptions?
        return (V) new Moped((MopedOptions) options);
    }
    return null;
}
```

EDIT: **visitor pattern**

To get rid of these casts you could use the visitor pattern.
Therefor you have to change your factory.
Note that the methods must not be `static`.
And if you get some more vehicles you have to add a method for it.

```
public Car visit(CarOptions options) {
    return new Car(options);
}

public Moped visit(MopedOptions options) {
    return new Moped(options);
}
```

You also have to add the abstract method `V visit(Factory visitor);` to `interface Options<V extends Vehicle>`.
The implementation is that simple:

```
public class CarOptions implements Options<Car> {
    // other methods
    @Override
    public Car visit(Factory visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class MopedOptions implements Options<Moped> {
    // other methods
    @Override
    public Moped visit(Factory visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

With this pattern there is no need to check `getType()` or `instanceof`.
You can simply call `Car car = new CarOptions().visit(new Factory());`

Comment: To cut down on casting you could consider using the visitor pattern to distinguish the different option types.

Comment: @michid done, hope that's the way you mentioned (I've never worked with this pattern before)

Answer (score 0):

There's countless ways to achieve this, but it resembles homework so I'll stick with the quick (not the best) solution.

The first thing is to either make your `CarOptions` and `MopedOptions` classes either `extend` the `Options` class, or make the`Options` class an interface, I did the latter.

Then I have setup `Vehicle` and `Moped` up to accept the `Options` interface. Here you didn't have class fields for the options properties.

I also changed the way you were trying to fetch the class details in the `getVehicle()` method to compare the class name against the options class name.

Generics (e.g. class Clazz) would be a much better way of doing this, but I suspect you'll get to generics after you're done with polymorphism and inheritance

```java
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factory f = new Factory();
        Options opts = new MopedOptions();
        Vehicle v = f.getVehicle(opts);
        System.out.println(v.getClass().getSimpleName());
        //Output: "Moped"
    }
    
}

class Factory {

    public Vehicle getVehicle(Options options) {
        if (options.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("CarOptions")) return new Car(options);
        if (options.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MopedOptions")) return new Moped(options);
        return null;
    }
}

class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    private final Options carOptions;
    public Car(final Options carOptions) { this.carOptions = carOptions; }
}

class Moped extends Vehicle {
    private final Options mopedOptions;
    public Moped(final Options mopedOptions) { this.mopedOptions = mopedOptions; }
}

interface Options {
    // methods
}

class CarOptions implements Options {
    // methods
}
 
class MopedOptions implements Options {
    // methods
}
```

---

## -- EDIT --

I'm a little unclear about whether the `Car` and `Moped` classes 'must' handle their respective specific options, but if so that's fine, just leave them strict and cast the options to their specific child instance like this

```java
class Factory {

    public Vehicle getVehicle(Options options) {
        if (options.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("CarOptions")) 
            return new Car((CarOptions)options);
        if (options.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MopedOptions")) 
            return new Moped((MopedOptions)options);
        return null;
    }
}

class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    private final CarOptions carOptions;
    public Car(final CarOptions carOptions) { this.carOptions = carOptions; }
}
class Moped extends Vehicle {
    private final MopedOptions mopedOptions;
    public Moped(final MopedOptions mopedOptions) { this.mopedOptions = mopedOptions; }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `options instanceof CarOptions` because your code will not work with lets say `SuperCarOptions extends CarOptions`.

Comment: Of course, if further inheritance is expected then that's one solution, and there's other ways this code can be improved for sure. However, I believe that's beyond the scope of answering the current question

Comment: This isn't homework. This is an oversimplification of a problem. I did arrive at the same conclusion @StefanWarminski had in his first answer but I was not satisfied with it as I thought there must be a more elegant way of constructing the factory, hence the question.